# How can I improve the response time of my color detection script in Python?

Tags: python, colors, detection

I made a script that detects a certain color on screen and presses the left click.

Its averaging around 0.150-170ms and im trying to lower it.I Have added the tolerance function and put it to 50 and its get consistently around 0.150-160ms. IS there any way to make it react faster. Im looking to get sub 0.100ms.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.00)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(893, 496, (113, 109, 51), tolerance=51):
        click(893, 496)
```